# WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux - Change Apache document Root folder on NTFS partition

Tags: apache2, ntfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have successfully enabled and installed the WSL on my Windows 10 laptop, after the anniversary update. I also have installed apache.

The default apache webpage is available at http://localhost so it works.

What I would like to do is to change the **document root configuration** to the mounted Windows disk partition, in **/mnt/d/Dropbox/blog**. I have checked the blog folder and set :

```
chown to www-data:www-data
chmod to 755
```

After service restart, I get the

> Apache 403 Forbidden Error

I have checked over the internet, but no serious issue. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a `Directory` directive for that folder that grants access?

Comment: Is your /mnt/d/Dropbox/blog in a Windows partition?

Comment: Yes this is a NTFS partition (it is my laptop - host machine partition)

Comment: From the linux console, I can read and write files, set the correct permissions. I have seen some threads in which they unmount and mount again the partition, but that should not be possible since I'm running Ubuntu from WSL... Anyway, I have asked my question on Github so developers can tell us more about how is the ubuntu machine integrated in WSL... See here : [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1015)https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1015

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu for Windows 10: All files are own by root and I cannot change it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911804/ubuntu-for-windows-10-all-files-are-own-by-root-and-i-cannot-change-it)